# min-height doesn't scale

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I want to scale a image in all IE Browsers.

My Code:

```
<div class="outer"><img src="text.png" /></div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
img {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Like this the img-Tag makes a autoscale with the width. But that doesn't work in IE. The Image just scale vertical.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You can't use percentage values for both elements..

Comment: What versions of IE are you targeting? And what actual result do you want? For the image to scale its height relative to the width of the browser? Meaning the image will always be at 100% width?

Comment: You are giving only  min-height: 100%; then it must scale vertical... try min-width-100%;

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image width to always span the entirety of the browser window, you have to ensure you set the `body` and parenting containers (in this case `outer`) to have `width: 100%` so that width percentages work correctly for descendants. Then, set an explicit width to the image at `100%` and the height should scale automatically.

```
body, .outer {
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmNub/1/)

Answer (score 0):

According to **[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**,

> If the height of the containing block is not explicitly set, then the element has no minimum height and the min-height property is interpreted as 0%.

You need to mention height to the parent container explicitly.

```
body{height: 800px;}  /* set your own height here */
```

According to **[Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height)**

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (that is, it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as zero.

Comment: @zoom23 please go through the provided msdn link. that clearly explains the complete behaviour of IE browsers.